# Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong to setup this Robot class in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, awt, awtrobot

I started learning Java last week so bear with me as I'm just getting the hang of things. I'm trying to make a class that extends the Java Robot class.

I am getting an "Identifier Expected" on this line:

```
    public ChanseyRobot(bot)
```

Robot Class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class ChanseyRobot extends Robot
{
private Robot bot;

public ChanseyRobot(bot)
{
    try
    {
        this.bot = new Robot();
    }
    catch (AWTException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ChanseyRobot robot = new ChanseyRobot(robot);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll also need to change how you're instantiating the `ChanseyRobot` class ...the current line (`ChanseyRobot robot = new ChanseyRobot(robot);`) is a recursive / tautological statement.

Comment: Besides 'making a short example', is there any reason the code is extending robot as opposed to just using one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **provide** the `type of the parameter` in your constructor.

change

```
public ChanseyRobot(bot)
```

to

```
public ChanseyRobot(Robot bot)  throws AWTException
```

You also need to declare `AWTException` in your constructor declaration as [**Robot's default constructor**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) throws AWTException.

```
public Robot()
      throws AWTException
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
public ChanseyRobot(bot) { }
```

to

```
public ChanseyRobot(Robot bot) { }
```

You need to declare Data Type before the variable name, and it is a very basic of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Java Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Your class IS A robot. So it doesn't need to create a `Robot bot` internally too.

```
public class ChanseyRobot extends Robot
{
    public ChanseyRobot()
    {
    }
}
```

And then just :

```
ChanseyRobot robot = new ChanseyRobot();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Robot Class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class ChanseyRobot extends Robot
{
private Robot bot;

public ChanseyRobot()
{
    try
    {
        this.bot = new Robot();
    }
    catch (AWTException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

### Main Class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ChanseyRobot robot = new ChanseyRobot();
    }
}
```